# dynamically generate a windows 10ish tile-menue in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, windows-10-desktop

Does anybody know a good way to generate tiles, sorted by groups dynamically?

Something like the tile view in windows 10(or in this case a devexpress example) [image: Win 10 inspired Tile-Menue]

The goal is to programmatically add groups or tiles by something like this: list.add("groupname","tilename"). So the groupname would be a primary key of group and a foreignkey of tile.

Comment: Are you asking how to do the graphical part or you're asking how to create groups in a model?

Comment: i'd like to know both tbh

Comment: For the design part, I would strongly recommend that you switch to WPF instead of Winforms if that's possible for you. It'll be much simpler to do something like that. For the model part, check Linq's Group by method, that should help.

Comment: alright thanks, unfortunately i cannot switch to WPF as this is going to be implemented in a Windows Forms Project

Comment: There are ways to include WPF elements in a WinForms app, you'll have to see if that could work for you.

Comment: yeah I've read a blog about it, but i don't think it will work in this case, thank you anyway though

Comment: If you can live with the groups being ordered vertically and their headers not being able to be styled why not use the ListVIew? It will look and do pretty much like what you show with only a few lines in the DrawTems event: `Brush brush = e.Item.Selected ? Brushes.LightSkyBlue : Brushes.LightSlateGray;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Item.Text, listView1.Font, 
                                    e.Bounds, Color.White);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example I created to help you get started with the model part.

Let's say you have a Tile class that represents your tile. In that case, I put directly the group name as part of the tile, but you could also have a `Group` class and store the `GroupId` in the Tile.

```
public class Tile
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
}
```

Now, let's say you have created a few tiles like so :

```
 var tiles = new Tile[] {
     new Tile { Title = "Tile 1", Group = "Group 1" },
     new Tile { Title = "Tile 2", Group = "Group 1" },
     new Tile { Title = "Tile 3", Group = "Group 1" },
     new Tile { Title = "Tile 4", Group = "Group 2" },
     new Tile { Title = "Tile 5", Group = "Group 2" },
     new Tile { Title = "Tile 6", Group = "Group 2" }};
```

Now, you can group tiles by the `Group` parameter using a simple Linq query:

```
var groupedTiles = 
    from t in tiles
    group t by t.Group into g
    select new { Group = g.Key, Tiles = g.ToList() };
```

`groupTiles` will contain a list of "groups" that will contain each the list of attached tiles. You should be able to easily bind that to your view.

Here's a console output:

```
foreach (var group in groupedTiles)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(group.Group);

    foreach (var tile in group.Tiles)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("\t" + tile.Title);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay ... that's the memory structure shaped in groups and tiles but this does not help him to create a Win10 like UI without showing him to render these groups and tiles in GDI+.

Comment: Check his comments under his question, he specifically asked for help on both the GUI side and the model side. That was my contribution for the model side.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot use the DevExpress control and you don't want to create an own custom drawn control (which I would recommend then), you could try to use stacked FlowLayoutPanels:

Put the top-level FlowLayoutPanel on a form an set its FlowDirection to LeftToRight (the blue one).

For each group you want to have, add a child FlowLayoutPanel with FlowDirection.TopDown (the green ones).

[image]

So the green ones are your groups, the tiles you want to have are the controls inside each group (the red squares).

Note that this is just an idea to achieve that behavior with default WinForms mechanisms. I don't think that this will scale well with many controls in use.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to look into FlowLayoutPanels, i might be able to use the DevExpress control though